# Bash script gets the same exist status for different outcomes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My script looks for a file, grep a pattern and if it matches, copies the file to a destination folder. I do that using pipe as you can see.
The whole command is working properly however I can't test it because I geting the same exit status, whether the file is found or not. 
To illustrate that,below I have two examples.  In the first, I found the the file and grepped the file. Note the exit status printed.
In the second example I didn't find and grepped the file however the exit status are the same.
What can I do to test this command properly?

1. The  file exist.

   ```
   find $HOME -type f -name arq_*.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} grep -l 00819047 {}  | xargs -n1 -I{} cp -v {} $HOME/aka 

   `/home/fabrifb/arq_144.txt' -> `/home/fabrifb/aka/arq_144.txt'

   echo "0)${PIPESTATUS[0]} 1)${PIPESTATUS [1]} : 2)${PIPWSTATUS[2]} ?)$? @)${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   0)0 1)0 : 2) ?)0 @)0 0 0
   ```
2. It doesn't exist

   ```
   find $HOME -type f -name arqX_*.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} grep -l X00819047 {}  | xargs -n1 -I{} cp -v {} $HOME/aka

   echo "0)${PIPESTATUS[0]} 1)${PIPESTATUS [1]} : 2)${PIPWSTATUS[2]} ?)$? @)${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
   ```

   Result

   ```
   0)0 1)0 : 2) ?)0 @)0 0 0
   ```

I expect to be able to differentiate both situations so that I can warn the user when the file doesn't exists.

Comment: please reformat your question with proper inline code and code blocks with syntax highlight See: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Which file exists or not? In which command? It is unclear. You give some unrelated commands, and state something is different in the environment. Please be exact. Please create an MCVE. Should be trivial to provide some `touch arqX_{1..3}.txt` and `echo X00819047 > argX_4.txt` to replicate the behavior on online bash runners ex. [repl](https://repl.it/languages/bash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns zero if it doesn't find any files. `grep` returns 1, but it never receives any file names because it's been wrapped in `xargs`, which again returns 0 for empty input. If you want to check the files exist you can either use arrays:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(arq_*.txt)
if [[ "${#files[@]}" -eq 0 ]]
then
    [handle non-existing files]
fi
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    if grep 00819047 "$file"
    then
        cp "$file" $HOME/aka
    fi
done
```

or a guard variable:

```
found=0
for file in arg_*.txt
do
    found=1
    [loop contents like above]
done
if [[ "$found" -eq 0 ]]
then
    [handle non-existing files]
fi
```

You also have a spelling mistake `PIPWSTATUS`. But in any case `${PIPESTATUS[@]}"` is all you need to print to get the full contents of that array.

Answer (score 0):

The find command returns 0 (success) unless there is a error, find will not return an error when no files match your argument.

> find exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur.

You probably should use a conditional statment to check if a file was found that matches the pattern.

```
if [ $(find $HOME -type f -name arq_*.txt) -gt 0 ]
then
   echo "no matching file found"
else
   echo "files found"
fi
```